# How to generate the Java classes for WSDL file in Hybris?

Tags: ant, wsdl, sap-commerce-cloud, wsimport

As a part of a requirement, I am supposed to consume a Soap web service, the WSDL of the web service is available to me.

I implemented it by generating the classes using auto generating tools like wsimport.But I was curious whether there are better ways of doing this in Hybris, for instance by including the task in ant to generate these classes automatically. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hybris working on spring framework, so I prefer using spring related libraries for SOAP client.

On the other hand hybris wake up time very long for developing/debugging web services. I prefer again creating independent jar library with same hybris spring version for service with shared interface with hybris. Generally integrations needs change by time. It is easy to only update this jar file. Also you can create mock jar for test environment with same interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.Can you please share some links for me to get started?